# Select from 2 tables cause errors

Tags: mysql, sql

I got 2 MySQL tables

"MerchantAccount"
It has the following columns;

- provider
- used
- inactive
- maxPerMonth

Then I have another table as the tracker how many have been used per month.

"merchantprocessing"
It has the following columns;
- id
- date
- mid (`provider` from ' MerchantAccount '

What I want is for it to find a random PROVIDER that hasn't used its maximum per month, as in "maxPerMonth", for example, 1500 transactions, there must be maxed for a provider. It must print a random provider in order so that all the transactions are correctly distributed over all the providers in the table (hence the use of used+1). The way to find monthly transactions on the relevant provider is in the "merchantprocessing" table. Has tried down, but does not work

I try to http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/03b168/26

```
SELECT a.provider, a.inactive, b.mid, b.date, a.used,
   Count(b.id) AS usedThisMonth
FROM   merchantaccount a, 
   merchantprocessing b
WHERE  a.inactive = '0'
   AND ( a.provider = b.mid 
         AND Year(b.date) = Year(CURRENT_DATE()) 
         AND Month(b.date) = Month(CURRENT_DATE()) 

       ) 
       AND a.used < usedThisMonth
   ORDER  BY a.used ASC 
   LIMIT  1 `
```

Unknown column 'usedThisMonth' in 'where clause'

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: Since you have that `count()`, you need a `GROUP BY` clause as well.

Comment: Column aliases (e.g. usedThisMonth ) aren't available in the WHERE clause. What are you trying to do?!? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
SELECT a.provider, a.inactive, b.mid, b.date, a.used,
       Count(b.id) AS usedThisMonth
FROM   merchantaccount a, 
       merchantprocessing b
WHERE  a.inactive = '0'
       AND ( a.provider = b.mid 
             AND Year(b.date) = Year(CURRENT_DATE()) 
             AND Month(b.date) = Month(CURRENT_DATE()) 

           ) 
GROUP  BY a.provider, a.inactive, b.mid, b.date, a.used
HAVING a.used < Count(b.id)
LIMIT 1
```

Please take note that this will not produce any rows as none of them fulfill the clause `a.used < Count(b.id)`.

Comment: It has to select rows that is not "full". Every provider has their own "maxPerMonth" in table, which is ex. 1500. Then it has to check if the provider has been used as maxium from table merchantprocessing from this month. Does that make sense

Answer (score 0):

This gives you the comparison of the amount used and the maximum amount per merchant per month:

```
select a.provider, a.inactive,
       year(p.date), month(p.date),
       count(p.id) as used_this_month,
       a.maxPerMonth
from merchantaccount a join 
     merchantprocessing p
     on a.provider = p.mid 
where a.inactive = 0  -- no quotes, because this is a number
group by a.provider, a.inactive, a.maxPerMonth,
         year(p.date), month(p.date);
```

You can add `having a.maxPerMonth >= count(b.id)` to get the ones that have exceeded the maximum.

You can add `p.date >= curdate() - interval (1 - day(curdate()) day` to get only data from the current month.